# Error Calculating Spark DataFrame Calculate Standard Deviation

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, standard-deviation

I have the following simple function where I'm filling all the columns missing values with a 0 and then calculating the Standard deviation. I know I could use the describe function, but I wanted to use this one for my purpose.

```
def stdDevAllColumns(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  df.select(df.columns.map(c => df.select(c).na.fill(0).agg(stddev(c))): _*)
}
```

This compiles, but results in a failure when run:

```
<console>:143: error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  [U1](c1: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U1])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U1] <and>
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)
         df.select(df.columns.map(c => df.select(c).na.fill(0).agg(stddev(c))): _*)
```

Any suggestions on what this could point out to?

EDIT: There is a much simpler way to do this as below:

```
z.show(df.summary("stddev"))
```

But nevertheless, I would like to know what the problem is with my implementation function above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occuring because Spark can't find a method on `DataFrame` with the correct signature. Sometimes it helps to break down the expression into smaller parts to see what is happening:

```
val df: DataFrame = ???
val fn: Array[DataFrame] = df.columns.map(c => df.select(c).na.fill(0).agg(stddev(c)))
def stdDevAllColumns(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  df.select(fn: _*) // compiler correctly complains
}
```

When we extract your select expression into a variable `fn` the compiler correctly infers that it has type `Array[DataFrame]`. There is no `select` method on `DataFrame` that takes this type as an input.

Comment: Ok got it, but what is the fix to this?

Comment: There isn't a simple fix. Each of the  `DataFrame`s generated by the `fn` expression is a `DataFrame` of a single column. To put them back together again you'd have to use some combination of `reduce` and `unionByName`.

Comment: Like I posted in my solution, the df.summary("stddev") does exactly what I want.